# "Modal Dialog" in WPF - make overlay block key events

Tags: wpf, events, key, overlay, block

I'm creating a WPF application containing a "Main-Content" - Layer containing a TabControl and a "Dialog" - Layer containing an ItemsControl.

The XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid>
  <TabControl>
    ..Some Tabs
  </TabControl>

  <ItemsControl>
      <ContentControl Content={Binding Dialog1Property} />
      <ContentControl Content={Binding Dialog2Property} />
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Usually "Dialog1Property" and "Dialog2Property" are null which means the ItemsControl is invisible. Whenever I assign a Control to one of them, it is shown in front of the TabControl which is exactly what I want. If I assign a gray Rectangle with an opacity of 0.7 to one of the Dialog - Properties it creates a Gray overlay.

If I click on the Tab, which is slightly visible through the overlay, nothing happens - the Rectangle blocks Mouse Events. It is, however, still possible to focus the TabControl behind the overlay using the Tab-Key and therefore it is also possible to switch tabs even though a Dialog is shown.

Is there an easy way to tell the rectangle to somehow block key events as it allready does with Mouseclicks?

Regards
BBRain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on your Rectangle, subscribe to the event PreviewKeyDown.

```
<Rectangle Opacity="0.7" Fill="Green" PreviewKeyDown="Rectangle_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

In its handler, simply set e.Handled = true;

```
private void Rectangle_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Since routed events prefixed with "Preview..." are tunneling, the elements under your rectangle won't recieve the input.

Comment: This would probably solve the problem if the PreviewKeyDown - Event would be fired, which doesn't seem to be the case. Any idea why? The PreviewMouseDown - Event is fired properly. Of course that doesn't help me much since Mouseclicks are being blocked allready...

Comment: I circumvented the problem by using a textbox at the end of my XAML. I then created a DataTrigger reacting to changes of the "IsFocused" Property of that textbox where I set the Focus to the first element in my Dialog via the FocusManager AttachedProperty so the focus sort of loops in my dialog. I'm gonna accept your answer anyways since it sounds like the correct solution and the reason it's not working in my case is probably a problem related to the rest of my sourcecode.